# How do I show all rows?

Tags: bootstrap-table

I don't want pagination... or a scrollable table. I don't want to specify a height but if you don't it default to something.

I just want my regular old table with sorting options.

(I'm using bootstrap-table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only set the `sortable` column option and don't set the `height` option:

```
<table data-toggle="table"
       data-url="your-json-url">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th data-field="id" data-sortable="true">ID</th>
        <th data-field="name" data-sortable="true">Name</th>
        <th data-field="price" data-sortable="true">Price</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wenyi/e3nk137y/3500/

Comment: That's exactly the behavior I would have expected to see.  I must have something else mucking up the height then.  Appreciate the fiddle.